# get list of facebook usernames from list of ids

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve the usernames of a lot of facebook users, given that I have their facebook ID. I could run a for loop that creates a lot of requests to Facebook graph API but this is pretty inefficient.

Is there a way to send let's say a Json with all the facebook IDs and retrieve the detailed public data?

Comment: Considering `username` does not even exist as a field any more in API v2.0., I question if it’s worth the trouble. Anyway, one of your keywords is _Batch Requests_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, the field `username` is no longer available in v2.0.

To request info for several Users at once via Graph API, you can use the following syntax:

```
GET /?ids={user_id_1},{user_id_2},{user_id_n}&fields={field_1},{field_1},{field_n}
```

Replace `{field_n}` with the respective fields you want to get returned, and `{user_id_n}` with the (app-specific) User IDs.